# Three points: $A=(4,3), B=(2,5)$, and $C=(3,6)$. Find the angle between vector $AB$ and vector $AC$.

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

Okay, so where am I going wrong? Here is step by step what I tried.

First I did this to find vectors:
$a=[A_x-B_x, A_y-B_y]$ so $a=[2,-2]$

$b=[A_x-C_x, A_y-C_y]$ so $b=[1,-3]$

Then I found the magnitudes of both vectors:

$$\|a\|= \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \text{ so } \|a\|= 0$$

$$\|b\|=\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \text{ so } \|b\| = \sqrt{10}$$

Then with this new information I tried the dot product:
$$\frac{a\cdot b}{\|a\|\cdot \|b\|} \text{ so } \frac{(2\cdot -2)+(1\cdot -3)}{0\cdot \sqrt{10}}$$
My calculator says "DIVIDE BY 0 Error"

So I assume I needed to try this:
$$\frac{(2 \cdot -2)+(1 \cdot -3)}{\sqrt{10}}= \frac{-7\sqrt{10}}{10} = -2.213594362$$

inverse of cos(-2.213594362)=DOMAIN ERROR

Comment: $||a||=\sqrt{8}$

Comment: Well, $\vec a$ has non-zero coordinates, so its magnitude shouldn't be zero.

Comment: Please ensure you are using grouping symbols in the correct places.

Comment: I tried showing you how you can use typesetting with MathJax and LaTeX to typeset your calculations. That is good to do as it increases the chances of good responses.

Comment: Umm... how are you getting $0$ for $\|a\|$ when both $x^2$ and $y^2$ are positive? $(-2)^2=4$, not $-4$.

Answer (score 2):

By drawing a picture it is completely trivial that $\widehat{A}=\arctan(3)-\arctan(1) = \arctan\frac{1}{2} \approx 26^\circ 33'54''$.

[image]

Comment: Nice graph! I don't have much experience with graphing software. Can you tell me what software you used to make the graph?

Comment: @quasi: this is just Geogebra: free and very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

we have $$\vec{AB}=(-2;2)$$ and $$\vec{AC}=(-1;3)$$ thus we have $$\cos(\theta)=\frac{2+6}{\sqrt{8}\sqrt{10}}$$
can you finish?

Comment: thank you for the hint, i have corrected it

Comment: Yes! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

**Here are some mistakes you've made:**

Note that $(-2)^2=4$, which is not equal to $-4$. Therefore, $\|\mathbf{a}\|\neq0$:
$$\|\mathbf{a}\|=\sqrt{2^2+(-2)^2}=\sqrt{4+4}=\sqrt{8}$$

---

Also, note that your [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) is incorrect. For vectors $\mathbf{a}=\begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\mathbf{b}=\begin{pmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \end{pmatrix}$, we should have:
$$\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{b}=a_1b_1+a_2b_2$$
Here is what you seem to have done instead:
$$\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{b}\neq a_1a_2+b_1b_2$$
Hence for your vectors, we should have:
$$\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{b}=\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -2 \end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -3 \end{pmatrix}=2+6=8$$

---

**The correction:**

Hence, you should have:
$$\cos{\theta}=\frac{\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{b}}{\|\mathbf{a}\|\|\mathbf{b}\|}=\frac{8}{\sqrt{8}\cdot \sqrt{10}}=\cdots$$
After simplifying, you should be able to find the value of $\theta$.